# Unable to change maven home at Ubuntu

Tags: linux, maven, ubuntu

I am trying to Ubuntu see another maven_home. I tried all but still no success. The interesting thing when I open a terminal and write `export M2_HOME` it sees that maven_home and I can clean install with the version of maven that I provided.

But, when I close this terminal it still sees old maven profile. I changed and add `export M2_HOME` to the following places but still  same.

I changed `M2_HOME` at those files :

```
/etc/profile  
~/.bash_profile 
~/.bash_login 
~/.profile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look [at this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/866169) which more or less is suggesting:

1. Use `~/.profile`
2. Create a new script under `/etc/profile.d`
3. Use `/etc/environment`

Option 1 should work, however you might have to re-login to trigger `~/.profile`.